# Ignoring Duplicates on Max in GroupBy - Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've read this thread about grouping and getting max: [Apply vs transform on a group object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517425/apply-vs-transform-on-a-group-object).

It works perfectly and is helpful if your max is unique to a group but I'm running into an issue of ignoring duplicates from a group, getting the max of unique items then putting it back into the DataSeries.

Input (named df1):

```
date       val
2004-01-01 0
2004-02-01 0
2004-03-01 0
2004-04-01 0
2004-05-01 0 
2004-06-01 0
2004-07-01 0
2004-08-01 0
2004-09-01 0
2004-10-01 0
2004-11-01 0
2004-12-01 0
2005-01-01 11
2005-02-01 11
2005-03-01 8
2005-04-01 5
2005-05-01 0 
2005-06-01 0
2005-07-01 2
2005-08-01 1
2005-09-01 0
2005-10-01 0
2005-11-01 3
2005-12-01 3
```

My code:

```
df1['peak_month'] = df1.groupby(df1.date.dt.year)['val'].transform(max) == df1['val']
```

My Output:

```
date       val   max
2004-01-01 0     true #notice how all duplicates are true in 2004
2004-02-01 0     true
2004-03-01 0     true
2004-04-01 0     true
2004-05-01 0     true
2004-06-01 0     true
2004-07-01 0     true
2004-08-01 0     true
2004-09-01 0     true
2004-10-01 0     true
2004-11-01 0     true
2004-12-01 0     true
2005-01-01 11    true #notice how these two values 
2005-02-01 11    true #are the max values for 2005 and are true
2005-03-01 8     false
2005-04-01 5     false
2005-05-01 0     false 
2005-06-01 0     false
2005-07-01 2     false
2005-08-01 1     false
2005-09-01 0     false
2005-10-01 0     false
2005-11-01 3     false
2005-12-01 3     false
```

Expected Output:

```
 date       val   max
2004-01-01 0     false #notice how all duplicates are false in 2004
2004-02-01 0     false #because they are the same and all vals are max
2004-03-01 0     false
2004-04-01 0     false
2004-05-01 0     false 
2004-06-01 0     false
2004-07-01 0     false
2004-08-01 0     false
2004-09-01 0     false
2004-10-01 0     false
2004-11-01 0     false
2004-12-01 0     false
2005-01-01 11    false #notice how these two values 
2005-02-01 11    false #are the max values for 2005 but are false
2005-03-01 8     true  #this is the second max val and is true
2005-04-01 5     false
2005-05-01 0     false 
2005-06-01 0     false
2005-07-01 2     false
2005-08-01 1     false
2005-09-01 0     false
2005-10-01 0     false
2005-11-01 3     false
2005-12-01 3     false
```

For reference:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'val':[0, 0, 0, 0, 0 , 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11, 11, 8, 5, 0 , 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 3, 3],
'date':['2004-01-01','2004-02-01','2004-03-01','2004-04-01','2004-05-01','2004-06-01','2004-07-01','2004-08-01','2004-09-01','2004-10-01','2004-11-01','2004-12-01','2005-01-01','2005-02-01','2005-03-01','2005-04-01','2005-05-01','2005-06-01','2005-07-01','2005-08-01','2005-09-01','2005-10-01','2005-11-01','2005-12-01',]})
```

Comment: This question is not clear and you have too much data to illustrate your point. I don't know why you want to ignore duplicates.  The max of [5, 5, 2, 2] is the same as the max of [5, 2].

Comment: I need one value for max year or none if they're the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not the slickest solution, but it works.  The idea is to first determine the unique values appearing in each year, and then do your transform just on those unique values.

```
# Determine the unique values appearing in each year.
df1['year'] = df1.date.dt.year
unique_vals = df1.drop_duplicates(subset=['year', 'val'], keep=False)

# Max transform on the unique values.
df1['peak_month'] = unique_vals.groupby('year')['val'].transform(max) == unique_vals['val']

# Fill NaN's as False, drop extra column.
df1['peak_month'].fillna(False, inplace=True)
df1.drop('year', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: No, the `keep=False` keyword argument forces `drop_duplicates` to drop all copies of the duplicate data.  Without this keyword argument your concern would be valid, as `drop_duplicates` keeps the first duplicate record by default.  My code produces the expected output.

Comment: @Parfait That works like a charm. Thanks for taking a look and stepping through the logic!