# What is purpose of DataFrame.transform?

Tags: python, pandas

I see it's the same like apply and have a point only in the context of groupby.

This example from the docs:

```
df.transform(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std())
```

Produces the same like:

```
df.apply(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std())
```

What is purpose of transform without groupby?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apply vs transform on a group object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517425/apply-vs-transform-on-a-group-object)

Comment: I saw this question. It is related to using transform with groupby. My question is about DataFrame.transform.