# How .apply works in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, apply

I was going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47143056/5665430) question where Ted Petrou explains the difference between .transform and .apply

This is the DataFrame used

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'State':['Texas', 'Texas', 'Florida', 'Florida'], 
                   'a':[4,5,1,3], 'b':[6,10,3,11]})

      State  a   b
 0    Texas  4   6
 1    Texas  5  10
 2  Florida  1   3
 3  Florida  3  11
```

Function inspect is defined

```
def inspect(x):
    print(x)
```

When I call inspect function using apply, I get 3 dataframes instead of 2

```
df.groupby('State').apply(lambda x:inspect(x))
     State  a   b
2  Florida  1   3
3  Florida  3  11

     State  a   b
2  Florida  1   3
3  Florida  3  11

   State  a   b
0  Texas  4   6
1  Texas  5  10
```

Why am I getting 3 dataframes, instead of 2 while printing ? I really want to know how apply function works?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

> In the current implementation apply calls func twice on the first column/row to decide whether it can take a fast or slow code path. This can lead to unexpected behavior if func has side-effects, as they will take effect twice for the first column/row.