# python pandas find transacctions of the same amount

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe as below.

```
d = {'emp': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 'vendor': ['x', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'z', 'z'], 'date': [1,1,2,3,3,3], 'amount': [4.9, 4.8, 1, 6, 5.6, 5.4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df["rounds"]=np.ceil(df['amount'])
df 

   amount  date emp vendor  rounds
0     4.9     1   a      x     5.0
1     4.8     1   a      x     5.0
2     1.0     2   a      y     1.0
3     6.0     3   b      z     6.0
4     5.6     3   b      z     6.0
5     5.4     3   b      z     6.0
```

I want to create the `example` column which would have a unique number if the same `emp` has spent the same amount (column `rounds`) at the same `vendor` on the same day.

an employee could have multiple transactions matching this criteria or they could have 0 transactions matching this criteria

how could i proceed?

```
 example
    1
    1
    
    2
    2
    2
```

when a number is same in the `example` column, it indicates that all transactions that fall in one group

update 1

another example

if my dataframe is like below

`d = {'emp': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b'], 'vendor': ['x', 'x', 'y', 'y', 'z', 'z'], 'date': [1,1,2,2,3,3], 'amount': [4.9, 4.8, 1, 1, 5.6, 5.4]}`

then column `example` should have values '1,1,2,2,3,3'

Comment: Why 1 and 2 instead of 2 and 3 for 2 duplicate transactions and 3 duplicate transactions?

Comment: 1 and 2 are numbers to indicate similar transactions...all the transaction where there is 1 are in 1 group etc...

Comment: Why do you need sql?

Comment: So even though there are 2 identical transactions by employee a on day 1, you want the number to be 1?

Comment: @chrisz It can be any number. The main condition is that a number indicates all transactions that fall in one group

Comment: @RafaelC i felt that sql might be faster...but that is not a requirement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`duplicated` call within the `transform`, duplicated will find how many duplicate item for vendor you have for each group, then we just add them up, should achieve what you need , [transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517425/apply-vs-transform-on-a-group-object) you can check the link

```
df.groupby(['date','emp','rounds']).vendor.transform(lambda x : x.duplicated().sum())
Out[806]: 
0    1
1    1
2    0
3    2
4    2
5    2
Name: vendor, dtype: int64
```

After assign it back

```
df['example']=df.groupby(['date','emp','rounds']).vendor.transform(lambda x : x.duplicated().sum())
#yield
df
Out[808]: 
   amount  date emp vendor  rounds  example
0     4.9     1   a      x     5.0        1
1     4.8     1   a      x     5.0        1
2     1.0     2   a      y     1.0        0
3     6.0     3   b      z     6.0        2
4     5.6     3   b      z     6.0        2
5     5.4     3   b      z     6.0        2
```

Update :

```
df['key']=tuple(zip(df.emp,df.vendor,df.date,df.rounds)) 
df[df.duplicated('key',keep=False)].groupby('key').ngroup()+1
Out[831]: 
0    1
1    1
2    2
3    2
4    3
5    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Only one idea, assign to column :)

Comment: You also have to add `rounds` to your groupby.

Comment: Best solution by far

Comment: @wen could you explain your approach? and add `rounds` in your solution groupby list?

Comment: would this require data to be sorted by columns `emp, vendor, date, amounts, rounds`?

Comment: it is not working as intended...i have updated my question

Comment: the first line should be `df['key']=tuple(zip(df.emp,df.vendor,df.date,df.rounds))
` please update so that i can accept your answer

Comment: @Ni_Tempe done , haha always forget your rounds column

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how to do it in SQL, but using Pandas:

```
# dp is a list of boolean showing whether the elements have duplicates
# setting keep=False returns all the duplicated elements as True
dp = df.duplicated(['date', 'emp', 'rounds'], keep=False)

# dp.dff().ne() means if the next element is no longer a duplicate
# then it's true, cumsum just increments the id
df['example'] = dp.diff().ne(0).cumsum()

df

   amount  date emp vendor  rounds  example
0     4.9     1   a      x     5.0        1
1     4.8     1   a      x     5.0        1
2     1.0     2   a      y     1.0        2
3     6.0     3   b      z     6.0        3
4     5.6     3   b      z     6.0        3
5     5.4     3   b      z     6.0        3
```

Comment: is there a way to remove 2 associated with the third row from the example column? There is only transaction where we have 2 and i don't want to flag such transactions

Comment: and please briefly explain your logic for the entire solution so that i can learn from it..thanks

Comment: @Ni_Tempe Do you still want to keep the row and set it as NaN?

Comment: @Ni_Tempe If you want the row set to NaN, I think RafaelC 's way using groupby is more intuitive.

Comment: it is not working as intended...i have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
df["tmp"] = df.duplicated(subset = ["date", "amp", "rounds"])
df2 = df.set_index(["date", "emp"])
df2["example"]= df.groupby(["date", "emp"])["tmp"].sum()
df2 = df2.drop("tmp", 1).reset_index()

   date emp  amount vendor  rounds  example
0     1   a     4.9      x     5.0      1.0
1     1   a     4.8      x     5.0      1.0
2     2   a     1.0      y     1.0      0.0
3     3   b     6.0      z     6.0      2.0
4     3   b     5.6      z     6.0      2.0
5     3   b     5.4      z     6.0      2.0
```

---

We start with your provided `df`. The first line

```
df["tmp"] = df.duplicated(subset = ["date", "amp", "rounds"])
```

creates a temporary column that indicates whether a row is duplicated or not, i.e.

```
   amount  date emp vendor  rounds    tmp
0     4.9     1   a      x     5.0  False
1     4.8     1   a      x     5.0   True
2     1.0     2   a      y     1.0  False
3     6.0     3   b      z     6.0  False
4     5.6     3   b      z     6.0   True
5     5.4     3   b      z     6.0   True
```

The second and third lines

```
df2 = df.set_index(["date", "emp"])
df2["example"]= df.groupby(["date", "emp"])["tmp"].sum()
```

Just assign the sum of the groups of `date` and `emp` to column `example`. It does this by setting the indexes to be the same.

When two data frames have the same index, you can assign values of one to the other even if the number of rows is different: `pandas` will infer that values should duplicated as long as indexes are the same.

The last column just drops the `tmp`.

Comment: please explain your logic briefly

Comment: 1) in case of the line `df["tmp"] = df.duplicated(subset = ["date", "vendor", "rounds"])` why don't you have `emp` too? 2) would this solution require the data to be sorted by ascending order of columns `emp, vendor, date, amounts, rounds`?

Comment: Actually, I mean to be `emp` instead of vendor :) I don't think it needs to be sorted.

Comment: i feel that all 4 columns should be in the first statement! what are your thoughts?

Comment: With the data you provided, the impact is the same. Both yield the same result. So yeah you could keep both, but it depends on your real dataset

Comment: it is not working as intended...i have updated my question

Answer (score 1):

If you want a unique number associated with each grouping that is generated based on the values within that grouping, you can use a hashing function, like `md5`:

```
from hashlib import md5

cols = ['emp','rounds','vendor','date']

def get_unique_id(x):
    if len(x) > 1:
        unique_string = ''.join(x.astype(str).values.flatten()).encode('utf8')
        unique_hash = str(int(md5(unique_string).hexdigest(), 16))
        return unique_hash

# use groupby to get unique groupings, then compute group hash id
grouped = df.groupby(cols).apply(get_unique_id).reset_index()

# merge with original df
df.merge(grouped, how="left", on=cols).rename(columns={0:'example'})

   amount  date emp vendor  rounds                                  example
0     4.9     1   a      x     5.0  204218359197769197011002751402112550616
1     4.8     1   a      x     5.0  204218359197769197011002751402112550616
2     1.0     2   a      y     1.0                                     None
3     6.0     3   b      z     6.0   93359096665893457037712279020314596965
4     5.6     3   b      z     6.0   93359096665893457037712279020314596965
5     5.4     3   b      z     6.0   93359096665893457037712279020314596965
```