# How using python to groupby and scaling values?

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I would like to rescaled column `'w'`.

I have averaged `'w'`.

```
aveData_set = Data_Set.groupby(['buildingid', pd.Grouper(key='reporttime',freq='15T')])['w'].mean().reset_index()
```

aveData_set result:

[image: aveData_set result]

Then I would like each `24H` rescaling column `'w'`.

```
ScaleData_set = aveData_set.groupby(['buildingid', pd.Grouper(key='reporttime',freq='24H')])['w'].apply(lambda x: (x-x.min())/(x.max()-x.min())).reset_index()
```

But result is strange,some column have disappeared.

ScaleData_set result:

[image: ScaleData_set result]

I really need your help.Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output is expected, because scaling not aggregate values. It return `Series` with same size as original `DataFrame`.

So is possible create new column:

```
aveData_set['w_scaled'] = (aveData_set.groupby(['buildingid',
                                                pd.Grouper(key='reporttime',freq='1d')])['w']
                                      .apply(lambda x: (x-x.min())/(x.max()-x.min())))
```

Or reassign back:

```
aveData_set['w'] = (aveData_set.groupby(['buildingid',
                                          pd.Grouper(key='reporttime',freq='1d')])['w']
                               .apply(lambda x: (x-x.min())/(x.max()-x.min())))
```

Here [`apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) working like [`transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html), check better explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27951930/2901002) with similar lambda function:

```
aveData_set['w'] = (aveData_set.groupby(['buildingid',
                                          pd.Grouper(key='reporttime',freq='1d')])['w']
                               .transform(lambda x: (x-x.min())/(x.max()-x.min())))
```

**Sample**:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03 18:09:04', periods=10, freq='7T')
Data_Set = pd.DataFrame({'reporttime': rng, 'w': range(10), 'buildingid':[39] * 5 + [40] * 5})
print (Data_Set)
           reporttime  w  buildingid
0 2017-04-03 18:09:04  0          39
1 2017-04-03 18:16:04  1          39
2 2017-04-03 18:23:04  2          39
3 2017-04-03 18:30:04  3          39
4 2017-04-03 18:37:04  4          39
5 2017-04-03 18:44:04  5          40
6 2017-04-03 18:51:04  6          40
7 2017-04-03 18:58:04  7          40
8 2017-04-03 19:05:04  8          40
9 2017-04-03 19:12:04  9          40
```

---

```
aveData_set = (Data_Set.groupby(['buildingid', 
                                 pd.Grouper(key='reporttime',freq='15T')])['w']
                       .mean().reset_index())
print (aveData_set)

   buildingid          reporttime    w
0          39 2017-04-03 18:00:00  0.0
1          39 2017-04-03 18:15:00  1.5
2          39 2017-04-03 18:30:00  3.5
3          40 2017-04-03 18:30:00  5.0
4          40 2017-04-03 18:45:00  6.5
5          40 2017-04-03 19:00:00  8.5

aveData_set['w'] = (aveData_set.groupby(['buildingid',
                                          pd.Grouper(key='reporttime',freq='1d')])['w']
                               .apply(lambda x: (x-x.min())/(x.max()-x.min())))

print (aveData_set)
   buildingid          reporttime         w
0          39 2017-04-03 18:00:00  0.000000
1          39 2017-04-03 18:15:00  0.428571
2          39 2017-04-03 18:30:00  1.000000
3          40 2017-04-03 18:30:00  0.000000
4          40 2017-04-03 18:45:00  0.428571
5          40 2017-04-03 19:00:00  1.000000
```

Comment: I am a python newbie and thank you for your help at one time.