# Pandas groupby + transform and multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

To obtain results executed on groupby-data with the same level of detail as the original DataFrame (same observation count) I have used the transform function.

Example:
*Original dataframe*

```
name, year, grade
Jack, 2010, 6
Jack, 2011, 7
Rosie, 2010, 7
Rosie, 2011, 8
```

*After groupby transform*

```
name, year, grade, average grade
Jack, 2010, 6, 6.5
Jack, 2011, 7, 6.5
Rosie, 2010, 7, 7.5
Rosie, 2011, 8, 7.5
```

However, with more advanced functions based on multiple columns things get more complicated. What puzzles me is that I seem to be unable to access multiple columns in a groupby-transform combination.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
               'b':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
               'c':['q', 'q', 'q', 'q', 'w', 'w'],  
               'd':['z','z','z','o','o','o']})

def f(x):
 y=sum(x['a'])+sum(x['b'])
 return(y)

df['e'] = df.groupby(['c','d']).transform(f)
```

Gives me:

```
KeyError: ('a', 'occurred at index a')
```

Though I know that following does work:

```
df.groupby(['c','d']).apply(f)
```

What causes this behavior and how can I obtain something like this:

```
a   b   c   d   e
1   1   q   z   12
2   2   q   z   12
3   3   q   z   12
4   4   q   o   8
5   5   w   o   22
6   6   w   o   22
```

Comment: Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27951930/9274732) it may help you to understand why

Comment: I observed the fact that columns become scalars by using print(x) within function f. But how do I overcome this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

for this particular case you could do:

```
g = df.groupby(['c', 'd'])

df['e'] = g.a.transform('sum') + g.b.transform('sum')

df
# outputs

   a  b  c  d   e
0  1  1  q  z  12
1  2  2  q  z  12
2  3  3  q  z  12
3  4  4  q  o   8
4  5  5  w  o  22
5  6  6  w  o  22
```

if you can construct the final result by a linear combination of the independent transforms on the same groupby, this method would work.

otherwise, you'd use a `groupby-apply` and then merge back to the original df.

example:

```
_ = df.groupby(['c','d']).apply(lambda x: sum(x.a+x.b)).rename('e').reset_index()
df.merge(_, on=['c','d'])
# same output as above.
```

Comment: Just realized I've posted the exact same alternative solution using a merge :)

Comment: For some reason rename causes items = [func(x) for x in index] TypeError: 'str' object is not callable.

Comment: In general you should avoid using built-ins with Pandas series / NumPy arrays. In fact, using the string `'sum'` instead of `sum` gets routed by Pandas to a tried and tested method which you should be able to rely on.

Comment: why do you `.reset_index()`? isn't `merge` faster with the index? and the index will guarantee the correct row ordering (some apply operations change ordering within groups)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `GroupBy` + `transform` with `sum` twice:

```
df['e'] = df.groupby(['c', 'd'])[['a', 'b']].transform('sum').sum(1)

print(df)

   a  b  c  d   e
0  1  1  q  z  12
1  2  2  q  z  12
2  3  3  q  z  12
3  4  4  q  o   8
4  5  5  w  o  22
5  6  6  w  o  22
```