# Shuffling one Column of a DataFrame By Group Efficiently

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to implement a permutation test on a large Pandas dataframe. The dataframe looks like the following:

```
    group  some_value  label
0       1           8      1
1       1           7      0
2       1           6      2
3       1           5      2
4       2           1      0
5       2           2      0
6       2           3      1
7       2           4      2
8       3           2      1
9       3           4      1
10      3           2      1
11      3           4      2
```

I want to group by column `group`, and shuffle the `label` column and write back to the data frame, preferably in place. The `some_value` column should remain intact. The result should look something like the following:

```
    group  some_value  label
0       1           8      1
1       1           7      2
2       1           6      2
3       1           5      0
4       2           1      1
5       2           2      0
6       2           3      0
7       2           4      2
8       3           2      1
9       3           4      2
10      3           2      1
11      3           4      1
```

I used `np.random.permutation` but found it was very slow.

`df["label"] = df.groupby("group")["label"].transform(np.random.permutation`

It seems that `df.sample` is much faster. How can I solve this problem using `df.sample()` instead of `np.random.permutation`, and  inplace?

Comment: What's wrong with `df['label'] = df.groupby("group")["label"].transform(pd.Series.sample, frac=1)`? Doesn't appear to be faster so I must be missing something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can using `sample` *Notice this is assuming `df=df.sort_values('group')`*

```
df['New']=df.groupby('group').label.apply(lambda x : x.sample(len(x))).values
```

Or we can do it by

```
df['New']=df.sample(len(df)).sort_values('group').New.values
```

Comment: Thanks! Do both methods assume that the dataframe is sorted by group?

Comment: @RyanR.Rosario yep that is assumed, but you can always adding df.sort_index(), get back the original order

Answer (score 0):

What about providing a custom transform function?

```
def sample(x):
    return x.sample(n=x.shape[0])

df.groupby("group")["label"].transform(sample)
```

This SO [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54080368/2955541) of printing out what is passed into the custom function via the transform function is helpful.