# pandas- change [ row_x , col_d ] value to [raw_y, col_a] based on comparison of [raw_x, col_b] & [raw_y, col_c]

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a table as below ( simplified one) 
[image]

I want to select each raw and  compare its Col_b value  with all other raw's Col_c value .  If they are equal, assign/append the matching raw's Col_a value to selected raw's Col_d value

Resultant table will look like below
[image]

The traditional method with multiple for/while loops I understand .  Is there some efficient ways in pandas , numpy etc to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `transform` and `np.where`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col_a':['A1','Z7.6','B1.1','C2','A1.3','P7.6'],
                  'Col_b':[120,-1,78,180,6,8],
                  'Col_c':[-7,45,120,32,180,120]})
def f(x):
    rowindx = np.where(df.Col_c == x)
    res = ' '.join(df.loc[rowindx[0], 'Col_a'])
    return res

df['Col_d'] = df['Col_b'].transform(f)
df
```

Output:

```
  Col_a  Col_b  Col_c      Col_d
0    A1    120     -7  B1.1 P7.6
1  Z7.6     -1     45           
2  B1.1     78    120           
3    C2    180     32       A1.3
4  A1.3      6    180           
5  P7.6      8    120
```

---

You can try this using `apply` and `np.where`:

```
def f(x):
    rowindx = np.where(df.Col_c == x.Col_b)
    res = ' '.join(df.loc[rowindx[0], 'Col_a'])
    return res

df['Col_d'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Col_a  Col_b  Col_c      Col_d
0    A1    120     -7  B1.1 P7.6
1  Z7.6     -1     45           
2  B1.1     78    120           
3    C2    180     32       A1.3
4  A1.3      6    180           
5  P7.6      8    120
```

Comment: Thanks , exactly  the one I was looking .  Found useful info on apply & transform form here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517425/apply-vs-transform-on-a-group-object