# How to keep only the consecutive values in a Pandas dataframe using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like the this:

[image]

I want to keep only the consecutive years in each group, such as the following figure where the year of 2005 in group A and year of 2009 and 2011 in group B are deleted.

[image]

I created a column of the year difference by using `df['year_diff']=df.groupby(['group'])['Year'].diff()`, and then only kept the rows where the year difference was equal to 1.

However, this method will also delete the first row in each consecutive year group since the year difference of the first row will be NAN. For example, the year of 2000 will be deleted from group 2000-2005. Is there a way that I can do to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### `shift`

Get the year diffs as OP first did.  Then check if equal to `1` or the previous value is `1`

```
yd = df.Year.groupby(df.group).diff().eq(1)
df[yd | yd.shift(-1)]

   group  Year
0      A  2000
1      A  2001
2      A  2002
3      A  2003
5      A  2007
6      A  2008
7      A  2009
8      A  2010
9      A  2011
10     B  2005
11     B  2006
12     B  2007
15     B  2013
16     B  2014
17     B  2015
18     B  2016
19     B  2017
```

---

#### Setup

Thx jez

```
a = [('A',x) for x in range(2000, 2012) if x not in [2004,2006]]
b = [('B',x) for x in range(2005, 2018) if x not in [2008,2010,2012]]
df = pd.DataFrame(a + b, columns=['group','Year'])
```

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly, using `diff` and `cumsum` create the additional group key, then `groupby` it and your group columns, and drop the `count` equal to 1.

```
df[df.g.groupby([df.g,df.Year.diff().ne(1).cumsum()]).transform('count').ne(1)]

Out[317]:
    g  Year
0   A  2000
1   A  2001
2   A  2002
3   A  2003
5   A  2007
6   A  2008
7   A  2009
8   A  2010
9   A  2011
10  B  2005
11  B  2006
12  B  2007
15  B  2013
16  B  2014
17  B  2015
18  B  2016
19  B  2017
```

---

Data

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'g':list('AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBB',
                 'Year':[2000,2001,2002,2003,2005,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2005,2006,2007,2009,2011,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017])]})
```

Comment: Dear @WeNYoBen, can you please kindly explain more about `transform('count')` function. I'm having some difficulties understanding this part since there is no column called "count". Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @yihaoren transform count , will assign the same count for each group , and you can check with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517425/apply-vs-transform-on-a-group-object

Comment: @yihaoren and count is the function transform ('function name')

Comment: Similar: `df[pd.Series([*zip(df.Year.diff().ne(1).cumsum(), df.group)]).duplicated(keep=False)]`

Comment: @piRSquared that is great sir :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can have two columns for differences. One for difference from the next row, and one from the previous row. Then you can use an np.where to filter the columns which have values of 1 for the first difference OR -1 for the second difference.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'group':list('AAAAAAAAAABBBBBBBBBB'),'Year':[2000,2001,2002,2003,2005,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2005,2006,2007,2009,2011,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017]})
df['year_diff']=df.groupby(['group'])['Year'].diff()
df['year_diff2']=df.groupby(['group'])['Year'].diff(-1)
df['check']=np.where((df.year_diff==1) | (df.year_diff2==-1),True,False)
```

And then drop all the rows where df.check==False.

This seems like a long method, but it is quite easy to logically follow the process I think.