# Pandas: Group by, Cumsum + Shift with a "where clause"

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to learn some Pandas that I otherwise would be doing in SQL window functions.

Assume I have the following dataframe which shows different players previous matches played and how many kills they got in each match.

```
 date          player        kills 
 2019-01-01      a             15
 2019-01-02      b             20
 2019-01-03      a             10
 2019-03-04      a             20
```

Throughout the below code I managed to create a groupby where I only show previous summed values of kills (the sum of the players kills excluding the kills he got in the game of the current row).

```
df['sum_kills'] =    df.groupby('player')['kills'].transform(lambda x: x.cumsum().shift())
```

This creates the following values:

```
 date          player        kills    sum_kills
 2019-01-01      a             15      NaN
 2019-01-02      b             20      NaN
 2019-01-03      a             10      15
 2019-03-04      a             20      25
```

However what I ideally want is the option to include a filter/where clause in the grouped values. So let's say I only wanted to get the summed values from the previous 30 days (1 month). Then my new dataframe should instead look like this:

```
 date          player        kills    sum_kills
 2019-01-01      a             15      NaN
 2019-01-02      b             20      NaN
 2019-01-03      a             10      15
 2019-03-04      a             20      NaN
```

The last row would provide zero summed_kills because no games from player a had been played over the last month. Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are a bit in a pinch using `groupby` and `transform`. As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517425/apply-vs-transform-on-a-group-object), `transform` operates on a single series, so you can't access data of other columns.
`groupby` and `apply` does not seem the correct way too, because the custom function is expected to return an aggregated result for the group passed by `groupby`, but you want a different result for each row.

So the best solution I can propose is to use `apply` without `groupy`, and perform all the selection by yourself inside the custom function:

```
def killcount(x, data, timewin):
    """count the player's kills in a time window before the time of current row.
    x: dataframe row
    data: full dataframe
    timewin: a pandas.Timedelta
    """
    return data.loc[(data['date'] < x['date']) #select dates preceding current row
            & (data['date'] >= x['date']-timewin) #select dates in the timewin                
            & (data['player'] == x['player'])]['kills'].sum() #select rows with same player

df['sum_kills'] = df.apply(lambda r : killcount(r, df, pd.Timedelta(30, 'D')), axis=1)
```

This returns:

```
        date player  kills  sum_kills
0 2019-01-01      a     15          0
1 2019-01-02      b     20          0
2 2019-01-03      a     10         15
3 2019-03-04      a     20          0
```

In case you haven't done yet, remember do parse `'date'` column to datetime type using [pandas.to_datetime](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) otherwise you cannot perform date comparison.