# Replicate excel countifs formula for all rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

New to python and I am trying to replicate excel COUNTIFS formula using pandas. COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,B:B,B2,C:C,C2)

[image: excel screenshot]

The countifs column in above screenshot shows my expected result.

Comment: Can you not show the link or picture ?

Comment: Can you also post your source data? It's unclear what you are trying to count and based on what conditions because the Excel cells are not labeled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have `groupby` + `transform`

```
df['countif']=df.groupby(['Col1','Col2','Col3'])['Col3'].transform('count')
```

Comment: Best solution! I only could have thought of a work around as I didn´t know ```transform``` yet. Thank you for posting this!

Comment: Thanks it worked. Is it possible to give a brief explanation on how it works.

Comment: @Suji https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517425/apply-vs-transform-on-a-group-object