# Is there any difference between Series.transform and Series.apply?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to grasp the differences between `transform` and `apply` methods of pandas. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47143056/4169361) answer was pretty helpful. The first major difference is only applicable to the case when `transform` is called from the DataFrameGroupBy object, so it's not affecting the calls from Series in any way. The second major difference is that `transform` performs checks to make sure that the output length of the method matches its input length. So I tried to come up with the test case where I call these methods from a Seires, and `apply` executes successfully while `transform` fails due to length difference. What I ended up with is this:

> some_series.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([1,2]))
>
> some_series.transform(lambda x: pd.Series([1,2]))

To my surprise, both of them successfully produced a DataFrame with two columns, in exactly the same way. If `transform` uses the `len()` function to check the length, that makes sense, since `len()` returns the number of rows, and that doesn't change. But then I'm having a hard time coming up with any situation where the number of rows could change, because it seems like the number of function calls that `transform/apply` make seems to be predetermined by the number of rows in the original Series, regardless of what exactly the function call returns.

So the question is, is there any situation where behaviors of `transform` and `apply` methods differ at all when called from a Series object? If not, it seems like only `apply` should be used, because it is faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up [posting this question on pandas GitHub](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/31937). It turns out the behavior of these two methods can be different after all. Specifically, `Series.apply()` always passes a single cell as a function argument, while `Series.transform()` can pass the entire Series as a function argument in some cases. I'm still not sure how this property can possibly be applied, since whatever can be done on a whole Series through transform may just as well be done on that Series directly. My only guess is shorter cleaner code, but can't say for certain to be honest.