# Pandas Apply vs Transform, when using Groupby and np.where

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am creating a series of calculations in my dataframe and have been using `apply()` successfully, until the one example below. Can anyone explain why `transform()` works in this instance but `apply()` does not (it doesn't throw an error, it just returns NaNs for the columns)? I've been doing operations of addition and subtraction with `apply()` successfully, so the new aspect is the `np.where()`.

None of the articles I can find address that apply should have this type of limitation. There is lots of information suggesting `transform()` should be more limiting, namely by only being only to process a single column at a time, and being forced to return a quantity of values equal to the series length.

```
df['val'] = compiled.groupby(['category']).B.apply(lambda x : np.where(x > 0, x, 0))

df['val'] = compiled.groupby(['category']).B.transform(lambda x : np.where(x > 0, x, 0))
```

Answer (score 3):

`df.groupby('category').V.apply(f)`, when `f` returns a numpy array, will return a dataframe with one item per category:

```python
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(1701)
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'category': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'B': np.random.randn(6)
})
df.groupby('category').B.apply(lambda x : np.where(x > 0, x, 0))
# category
# A    [0.0, 2.3759516516254156, 0.0]
# B                   [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
# Name: B, dtype: object
```

`df.groupby('category').V.transform(f)`, when `f` returns a numpy array, will return a dataframe with one item per row in the original dataframe:

```python
df.groupby('category').B.transform(lambda x : np.where(x > 0, x, 0))
# 0    0.000000
# 1    2.375952
# 2    0.000000
# 3    0.000000
# 4    0.000000
# 5    0.000000
# Name: B, dtype: float64
```

Since you are assigning the result to a column in the original dataframe, `transform` is the appropriate method to use.

Note that the behavior of `apply` is similar to that of `transform` if `f` returns a pandas Series, which may be why `apply` worked for you in the past.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47143056/2937831) for a more in-depth discussion of the differences between `apply` and `transform`.