# Pandas Transforming the Applied Results back to the original dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

Consider the following DataFrame:

```
candy = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Bob','Bob','Bob','Annie','Annie','Annie','Daniel','Daniel','Daniel'], 'Candy': ['Chocolate', 'Chocolate', 'Lollies','Chocolate', 'Chocolate', 'Lollies','Chocolate', 'Chocolate', 'Lollies'], 'Value':[15,15,10,25,30,12,40,40,16]})
```

After reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27517425/apply-vs-transform-on-a-group-object), I am aware that `apply()` works on the whole Dataframe and `transform()` works on one series at-a-time.

So if I want to append the total $ spend on candy per person, I can simply use the following:

```
candy['Total Spend'] = candy.groupby(['Name'])['Value'].transform(sum)
```

But if I need to append the total $ chocolate spend per person, it feels like I have no choice but to create a separate dataframe and then merging it back by using the `apply()` function since `transform()` only works on a series.

```
chocolate = candy.groupby(['Name']).apply(lambda x: x[x['Candy'] == 'Chocolate']['Value'].sum()).reset_index(name = 'Total_Chocolate_Spend')
candy = pd.merge(candy, chocolate, how = 'left',left_on=['Name'], right_on=['Name'])
```

While I don't mind writing the above code to solve this problem. Is it possible to `transform()` the `.apply()`'d results back to the dataframe without having to create a separate dataframe and `merge` it?

What is actually happening when the `transform()` function is used? Is a separate series being stored in memory and then merged back by the indexes similar to what I have done in the `apply` then merged method?

Comment: `apply(..., axis=0/1)` either works one-column-at-a-time (axis=0) or one-row-at-a-time (axis=1); `transform()` always works one column at-a-time

Comment: This question's title is way too general and is only asking how to use [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/10min.html#boolean-indexing) in an aggregation operation. It doesn't even necessarily need to use `transform`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not have much to add to the excellent reference you provided on apply vs. transform, but you can do what you want without creating a separate dataframe, for example you can do

```
candy.groupby(['Name']).apply(lambda x: x.assign(Total_Chocolate_Spend = x[x['Candy'] == 'Chocolate']['Value'].sum()))
```

this uses `assign` for each group in groupby to populate `Total_Chocolate_Spend` with the number you want

Comment: That is what I am looking for! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There are other methods.  For example:

Create a temp column with just the chocolate value using `df.where`:

```
candy["choc_val"] = candy.Value.where(candy.Candy =="Chocolate", other=0)
candy["Total_Chocolate_Spend"] = candy.groupby("Name").choc_val.transform(sum)
candy = candy.drop(columns="choc_val")
```

output:

```
     Name      Candy  Value  Total Spend  Total_Chocolate_Spend
0     Bob  Chocolate     15           40                     30
1     Bob  Chocolate     15           40                     30
2     Bob    Lollies     10           40                     30
3   Annie  Chocolate     25           67                     55
4   Annie  Chocolate     30           67                     55
5   Annie    Lollies     12           67                     55
6  Daniel  Chocolate     40           96                     80
7  Daniel  Chocolate     40           96                     80
8  Daniel    Lollies     16           96                     80
```

I don't know if this is more performant or easier to read.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, though I have accepted another answer by piterbarg as it preserves the original apply function.

Comment: You don't need to create an intermediate column, you can just directly use masking `lambda x: x[x['Candy'] == 'Chocolate']...`