# Ungroup pandas dataframe after bfill

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I'm trying to write a function that will backfill columns in a dataframe adhearing to a condition. The upfill should only be done within groups. I am however having a hard time getting the group object to ungroup. I have tried reset_index as in the example bellow but that gets an AttributeError.

Accessing the original df through `result.obj` doesn't lead to the updated value because there is no inplace for the groupby bfill.

```
def upfill(df:DataFrameGroupBy)->DataFrameGroupBy:
    for column in df.obj.columns:
        if column.startswith("x"):
            df[column].bfill(axis="rows", inplace=True)
    return df
```

Assigning the dataframe column in the function doesn't work because groupbyobject doesn't support item assingment.

```
def upfill(df:DataFrameGroupBy)->DataFrameGroupBy:
    for column in df.obj.columns:
        if column.startswith("x"):
            df[column] = df[column].bfill()
    return df
```

The test I'm trying to get to pass:

```
def test_upfill():
    df = DataFrame({
        "id":[1,2,3,4,5],
        "group":[1,2,2,3,3],
        "x_value": [4,4,None,None,5],
    })
    grouped_df = df.groupby("group")
    result = upfill(grouped_df)
    result.reset_index()
    assert result["x_value"].equals(Series([4,4,None,5,5]))
```

Comment: What you want to achieve is unclear. Can you add a simple input/output example?

Comment: So to add some explanation to the in/out of the test.
The expected values of the "x_value" column should be upfilled inside of the groups.
The None value remains in the expected series because in group 2 we have the values 4,None. The None doesn't get filled because it is after the 4.
In group 3 we have None, 5. The None should get back filled since it is before the 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use 'transform' method on the grouped DataFrame, like this:

```
import pandas as pd

def test_upfill():
    df = pd.DataFrame({
        "id":[1,2,3,4,5],
        "group":[1,2,2,3,3],
        "x_value": [4,4,None,None,5],
    })
    result = df.groupby("group").transform(lambda x: x.bfill())
    assert result["x_value"].equals(pd.Series([4,4,None,5,5]))

test_upfill()
```

[Here you can find](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47143056/9374372) find more information about the transform method on Groupby objects

Answer (score 1):

Based on the accepted answer this is the full solution I got to although I have read elsewhere there are issues using the obj attribute.

```
def upfill(df:DataFrameGroupBy)->DataFrameGroupBy:
    columns = [column for column in df.obj.columns if column.startswith("x")]
    df.obj[columns] = df[columns].transform(lambda x:x.bfill())
    return df
```

```
def test_upfill():
    df = DataFrame({
        "id":[1,2,3,4,5],
        "group":[1,2,2,3,3],
        "x_value": [4,4,None,None,5],
    })
    grouped_df = df.groupby("group")
    result = upfill(grouped_df)
    assert df["x_value"].equals(Series([4,4,None,5,5]))
```