# Calculation problem after pandas grouping

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

In pandas, how to achieve, grouped by date, in each date group, each row of column A and B multiplied and then summed, and then divided by the sum of all B columns in the date group.

I have tried:

```py
(df.groupby('date')['A','B']
    .transform(lambda x: (x['A'] * x['B']).sum())
    .div(df.groupby('date')['B'].agg('sum')))
```

and:

```py
(df.groupby('date')
    .transform(lambda x: (x['A'] * x['B']).sum())
    .div(df.groupby('date')['B'].agg('sum')))
```

both showed:

> KeyError: 'A'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) instead of `.transform()`, as follows:

```py
df.groupby('date').apply(lambda x: (x['A'] * x['B']).sum() / x['B'].sum())
```

By using `.apply()`, the `x` variables in the `lambda` function will be recognised as `DataFrame` objects representing each group, which can each be indexed for individual columns.

The `.transform()` method only treats `x` as a `Series` object representing only one column at a time.

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47143056/21283023):

> #### Two major differences between `apply` and `transform`
>
> There are two major differences between the `transform` and `apply` groupby methods.
>
> - **Input**:
>
>   - `apply` implicitly passes all the columns for each group as a **DataFrame** to the custom function.
>   - while `transform` passes each column for each group individually as a **Series** to the custom function.
> - **Output**:
>
>   - The custom function passed to **`apply` can return a scalar, or a Series or DataFrame (or numpy array or even list)**.
>   - The custom function passed to **`transform` must return a sequence** (a one dimensional Series, array or list) **the same length as the group**.
>
> So, `transform` works on just one Series at a time and `apply` works on the entire DataFrame at once.

#### Example

Sample data:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'date': ['01/01/1999', '02/01/1999', '03/01/1999', '03/01/1999'],
    'A': [2, 4, 7, 4],
    'B': [5, 7, 9, 6]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
```

```
         date  A  B
0  01/01/1999  2  5
1  02/01/1999  4  7
2  03/01/1999  7  9
3  03/01/1999  4  6
```

The calculation for `'03/01/1999'` would be:

```py
((7 * 9) + (4 * 6)) / (9 + 6) # = 5.8
```

Calculation for each date group using `.apply()`:

```py
df_ab_calc = df.groupby('date').apply(lambda x: (x['A'] * x['B']).sum() / x['B'].sum())
print(df_ab_calc)
```

```
date
01/01/1999    2.0
02/01/1999    4.0
03/01/1999    5.8
```