# Series not being passed to a UDF in .transform() in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

from what I've read from different answers on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47143056/20710312) and other resources, when providing the `.transform()` with a UDF, each column is passed one by one for each Group

But when i tried it myself, i saw a Dataframe being passed into the UDF

```py
df = pd.Dataframe({'State':['Texas', 'Texas', 'Florida', 'Florida'], 
                   'a':[4,5,1,3], 'b':[6,10,3,11]}
def inspect(x):
    print(type(x))

df.groupby('State').transform(inspect)

# Output 
# <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
# <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
# <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
# <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
# <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

the Dataframe passed to the `inspect` happens to be the Dataframe of the first group (State = Florida). But no one has mentioned and talked about a Dataframe being passed when working with UDFs while using `.transform()`.

my question is :

- Why is a Dataframe passed to the `inspect` function when everyone says a Series (each column) is passed to the UDF?
- why was the Dataframe of the first groupby object passed to the `inspect`? why wasn't the second groupby passed to the `inspect` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) documentation (see the highlighted part):

> The current implementation imposes three requirements on `f`:
>
> - `f` must return a value that either has the same shape as the input   subframe or can be broadcast to the shape of the input subframe.   For
>   example, if `f` returns a scalar it will be broadcast to have the  same shape as the input subframe.
> - if this is a DataFrame, `f` must support application column-by-column   in the subframe. **If `f` also supports application to the entire
>   subframe,   then a fast path is used starting from the second chunk.**
> - `f` must not mutate groups. Mutation is not supported and may   produce unexpected results. See [`Mutating with User Defined Function (UDF) methods`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/gotchas.html#gotchas-udf-mutation) for more
>   details.

I thus believe that `transform` is performing this check. Indeed, if we identify the order of the groups transforms using a counter, we indeed have successive numbers, except after the first group:

```
from itertools import count

df = pd.DataFrame({'State':['Texas', 'Texas', 'Florida', 'Florida', 'Washington'], 
                   'a':[4,5,1,3,2], 'b':[6,10,3,11,12]})

c = count()
def inspect(x):
    x = next(c)
    return x

df.groupby('State').transform(inspect)
```

Output, notice that step `2` is missing, likely when the check for a DataFrame happens:

```
   a  b
0  3  4  # second group (3 and 4)
1  3  4
2  0  1  # first group (0 and 1)
3  0  1
4  5  6  # third group (5 and 6)
```

Comment: i still can't understand why the DataFrame is being passed. to what i can understand from the doc, it's saying if `f` can be applied to the whole the DataFrame, then a faster path is used from the second group.
so that means passing the the first group as a DataFrame and seeing if `f`  can be applied to it, is how it's choosing to use the fast path? or have i misunderstood it completely?