# Pandas - group and transform with multiple arguments

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, transform

Here is my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'two', 'one'],
                   'B': ['Ar', 'Br', 'Cr', 'Ar', 'Ar'],
                   'C': ['12/15/2011', '11/11/2001', '08/30/2015', '07/3/1999', '03/03/2000'],
                   'D': [1, 7, 3, 4, 5],
                   'F': ['12/1/2011','10/1/2000','8/15/2015','12/1/2011','12/1/2011'] })
df['C'] = pd.to_datetime(df['C'])
df['F'] = pd.to_datetime(df['F'])
```

I would like to group by column `B` and then for each group check if column `C` contains date within 30 days of column `F`. I would get back an indicator column for the whole group, which should look like

```
df['indicator'] = [1,0,1,1,1]
```

here is what I tried:

```
def date_test(x, y):

    result = False
    for i in x.index:
        if x[i]<y[i]+ pd.Timedelta(days=30):
            result = True

    return result

df['indicator'] = df.groupby('B')['C','F'].transform(date_test).astype('int64')
```

But I got back `TypeError: Transform function invalid for data types`

So I guess I cannot pass two columns to transform function. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're right, the way .transform() works is that the function passed evaluates each column (C and F in this case) separately. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854476/pandas-transform-doesnt-work-sorting-groupby-output) for more details.

However, I think you can use .apply() and get the results you want:

```
>>> dfGroup = df.groupby('B')
>>> dfGroup.apply(lambda x: x['C'] < x['F'] + pd.Timedelta(days=30))
>>> B    
    Ar  0     True
        3     True
        4     True
    Br  1    False
    Cr  2     True
    dtype: bool
```

Comment: and to assign : `df['indicator'] = df.groupby('B').apply(date_test).swaplevel().reset_index(-1, drop=True)`

Comment: @Boud thank you for adding comment. It seems like the following also works  `df['indicator'] = df.groupby('B').apply(date_test).reset_index(0, drop=True)` or am I missing something

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will help you but something like :

```
df = {'1': 'one', '3': 'three', '2': 'two', '5': 'five', '4': 'four', 'indicator':[]}

if 'one' in df.values() == True:
    df['indicator'].append(1)
else:
    df['indicator'].append(0)
```

and then run it in a for loop to read all element in your `'C'`